Problem with mapping otlp resource attributes into loki labels (Serilog + Otlp Collector + Loki + Grafana)
I have a problem with OpenTelemetry configuration in my .NET 8 web app.
Logs are visible in the Grafana/Loki application, but I see only one label service_name with value unknown_service:dotnet.
When I configure Serilog to write logs directly to Loki (.WriteTo.GrafanaLoki(...)), everything works fine.
How to properly configure the entire application to be able to define my own labels in Loki?
My configuration:
Application (.NET):
OpenTelemetryBuilder builder
     = webAppBuilder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry().ConfigureResource(
         resBuilder => resBuilder.AddService(
            serviceName: resource.Name,
            serviceVersion: resource.Version,
            autoGenerateServiceInstanceId: false,
            serviceInstanceId: Environment.MachineName
        ));

builder.WithTracing(tracing => {
           tracing.AddSource("MyApp")
                  .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation(o =>
                   {
                     o.RecordException = true;
                   })
                  .AddHttpClientInstrumentation(h => h.RecordException = true)
                  .SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler())
                  .SetErrorStatusOnException()
                  .AddOtlpExporter(); // GRPC: http://localhost:4317

builder.WithMetrics(metrics => {
           metrics.AddMeter("MyApp")
                  .AddMeter(DiagnosticHeaders.DefaultListenerName)
                  .SetExemplarFilter(ExemplarFilterType.TraceBased)
                  .AddRuntimeInstrumentation()
                  .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
                  .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                  .AddProcessInstrumentation()
                  .AddOtlpExporter(); // GRPC: http://localhost:4317

webAppBuilder.Services.AddSerilog(
    (serviceProvider, configuration) =>
    {
      configuration.Enrich.WithProcessId()
                   .Enrich.WithThreadId()
                   .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                   .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                   .WriteTo.AddConsoleSink()
                   .WriteTo.OpenTelemetry() // GRPC: http://localhost:4317
    }
);


otel-collector.yaml (on Docker from image otel/opentelemetry-collector:latest):
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317
      http:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318

processors:
  batch:
    timeout: 3s                # Batch data for up to 3 seconds
    send_batch_size: 1000      # Number of spans or metrics per batch

exporters:
  prometheus:
    endpoint: ":9201"          # Prometheus remote write endpoint
    send_timestamps: true
    metric_expiration: 180m
    enable_open_metrics: true
  otlp/tempo:
    endpoint: tempo:4317       # Endpoint for Tempo to send traces
    tls:
      insecure: true
  otlphttp/loki:
    endpoint: http://loki:3100/otlp   # Endpoint for Loki to send logs
    tls:
      insecure: true 

extensions:
  health_check:

service:
  extensions: [health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlp/tempo]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [prometheus]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlphttp/loki]


Loki-config.yaml (on Docker from image grafana/loki:3.1.0)
limits_config:
  allow_structured_metadata: true

EDIT 1
A have changed serilog config
configuration.WriteTo.OpenTelemetry(options =>
{
   options.Endpoint = "http://localhost:4317"
   options.ResourceAttributes.Add("service.name", "MyAppName");
}

and now it works, but still I don't know how to configure custom "dynamic" labels.
For example if I log something like this
logger.LogInformation("Some message for {ModuleId}", moduleId);

I want to see ModuleId as Loki label. In GrafanaLoki serilog sink we have property PropertiesAsLabels and there we can list logs properties names. I don't know how to achieve this with OpenTelemetry.

That doesn't look like an OpenTelemetry issue. You're using Serilog for the logs, so this looks like an issue with Serilog. If you switch to using OpenTelemetry for logs, that should work fine, there's no need for Serilog if you're using ILogger.

I use Serilog, because I have more than one sink. In some app configuration I write logs to files or DB, so I want to have one log provider.

Like I said then, this is a Serilog issue, not an OpenTelemetrt one since you're not using OpenTelemetry for logs. OpenTelemetry does have the ability to do files and DBs, so it would be cleaner to move everything to that. Have a look at the OpenTelemetry collector exporters and running it as a sidecar, or raise an issue with Serilog Sink in their github.
